# Broke python3 source file (in multiprocessing)...how to reinstall python3 (.5.2) from scratch?

Tags: apt, 16.04, python3

So, I was trying to edit a file in the multiprocessing python library (/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing). I broke the file and forgot to keep a copy of the original. I guess I need to reinstall python3 from scratch. But doing:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3:amd64
```

and the broken file is still in the state I left it in~

How to exit this predicament?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file appears to be provided by package [libpython3.5-stdlib](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpython3.5-stdlib)

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing
libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64: /usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing
```

so you will probably need to re-install that

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.5-stdlib
```

Comment: Oh, wait, it fixed the file (despite the error message)

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: there seems to be no libpython3.5 (there is 3.7 to 3.9 and having 3.8-stdlib doesnt seem to help me :s)